# Sound output not switching dynamically on windows 10

Tags: windows-10, audio

When connecting a headset to my laptop computer, the sound is not rerouted to them. I can still change this by switching default output in the sound settings. The same thing happen when I remove the headset.

The headset is connected via the only analogic port available.

I found [this document related to Windows Vista](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/933144) which states that in some cases, this is the standard behaviour.

Is this behaviour a windows option that can be changed or is it due to a faulty driver ? (I have no access to the computer for now, so I can't update them).

Comment: What kind of headset? Analogue, Bluetooth, USB and what kind of sound card do you have and which ports do you use to connect the headset (if it's analogue)? It does make a different and e.g. for what's described in the article you linked, it states at the end: `This behavior is by design.`

Comment: @Seth Analogue headset. I connect them to the standart green port (I only have one). I don't have the reference for now, I'll update the question as soon as I have it.

Comment: what sound adaptor? If its realtek is it set to treat your speaker and sound card as seperate devices?

Comment: If it's an analogue headset it depends on your sound card an drivers, both need to support it. The sound card has to have a way to detect a device was plugged in and the driver has to act on it. Check your sound card/mainboard manual for the type and a description.